# android ndk using mupdf library

Tags: android, pdf, compilation, java-native-interface

I want to make a pdf viewer program in android phone. So, I purchased the mupdf library. 
I built the mupdf c++ classes and have 'libmibookreader.so' file.
And I also compiled the native function classes.
Then, I tried to run the application , but I have some errors.

Tag                Message
AndroidRuntime     java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: open

Comment: You 'purchased' the MuPDF library ? MuPDF is an open-source application. There is a commercial version, but if you are a customer you should contact Artifex for support. Also MuPDF isn't written in C++, so I'm kind of puzzled. Where did you get MuPDF from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you had not load library properly or may be you had not given the name properly in `System.load("libname");`

Comment: but I also used System.loadlibrary("libname");

Comment: can you post your Logcat Trace?

Answer (score 0):

What is your android version?
on 2.1 and before, the lib libjnigraphics.so is missing and the mupdflib need it

Comment: Hi. I am struggling with the same problem. Can you help me how to overcome this. Or is it even possible to run it on 2.1?